# Looping over a python list of tuples and applying a function

Tags: python, function, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame in this format:

```
  vid            points
0 1              [[0,1], [0,2, [0,3]]
1 2              [[1,2], [1,4], [1,9], [1,7]]
2 3              [[2,1], [2,3], [2,8]]
3 4              [[3,2], [3,4], [3,5],[3,6]]
```

Each row is trajectory data, and I have to find distance between the trajectories with a function `func_dist`, like this:

```
 x = df.iloc[0]["points"].tolist() 
 y = df.iloc[3]["points"].tolist()
 func_dist(x, y)
```

I have a list `l` of indices for trajectories of interest..

```
l = [0,1,3]
```

I must find the distance between all the possible pairs of trajectories; in the case above, this is 0-1, 0-3, and 1-3.  I know how to generate a list of pairs using

```
 pairsets = list(itertools.combinations(l, 2))
```

which returns

```
 [(0,1), (0,3), (1,3)]
```

Since the list may have over 100 indices, I am trying to automate this process and store the distances calculated between each pair in a `new_df` data frame.

I tried the following code for distance computation:

```
for pair in pairsets:
    a, b = [m[0] for m in pairssets], [n[1] for n in pairsets]
    for i in a:
        x = df.iloc[i]["points"].tolist()
    for j in b:
        y = df.iloc[j]["points"].tolist()
    dist = func_dist(x, y)
```

But it calculates only the last pair, 1-3.  How to calculate all of the pairs and create a new data frame like this:

```
  traj1       traj2       distance
  0           1           some_val
  0           3           some_val
  1           3           some_val
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a matter of handling your indices properly.
For each pair, you grab the two indices, assign your data sets, and compute the distance.

```
dist_table = []

for pair in pairsets:
    i, j = pair
    x = df.iloc[i]["points"].tolist()
    y = df.iloc[j]["points"].tolist()
    dist = func_dist(x, y)
    dist_table.append( [i, j, dist] )
```

You can combine the first two lines:

```
for i, j in pairsets:
```

The `dist_table` gives you a 2D list that you should be able to convert to a new data frame with a simple PANDAS call.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: This is perfect. I used "for pair in pairsets:" Also can you please let me know how can I convert the output to a df ?

Comment: Right.  One problem in the original code is that you *ignored* `pair` entirely once you got into the loop.

Comment: I'd have to look up the data frame conversion, although I do know it's pretty easy.  I use an internal package for data frames, rather than PANDAS.